# Android : Auto resize view for small screen

Tags: android, android-view

There is a solution to resize automatically the views of my android app?
I've optimized it for 7" screen.
But now I want to use it on 3.2" screen and it's looking horrible!

I've you got some ideas or I have to do it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the first stop I would recommend:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

This document explains the screens-support features provided by the platform and how you use them in your application. By following the practices described here, you can easily create an application that displays properly on all supported device screens and that you can deploy to any device as a single .apk."to any device as a single .apk.

and check this pdf: http://www.vanteon.com/downloads/Scaling_Android_Apps_White_Paper.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Define sizes/dimensions in the **dimens** folder, and set sizes to your Views programatically through Java.

Or, you could set the size based on some ratio, according to the screen size. I mean, you can calculate the width/height of the screen during runtime and make the dimensions of your view **screenwidth/x**.

Answer (score 0):

Please read this tutorials from Android developers:

- [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html)
- [Designing for Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html)