# How can I resize my ViewPager depends on the size of my screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, resize, android-viewpager

I'm trying to resize my ViewPager depends on the screen size of a device. My ViewPager is at the center of screen and has only a width of 300dp. I want my ViewPager height to resize depends on the screen size. Underneath of my ViewPager  it has a ImageView, this ImageView covers a part of my ViewPager.

In my activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/img_memtext"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>


<com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/indicator"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/notification_bg"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/attention"
    android:layout_below="@id/indicator"/>
```

In my viewpager_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="280dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/news_image"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/news_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/news_image"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/space"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_below="@+id/news_title"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/news_body"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/news_title"
                android:textSize="14dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/read_more"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/news_body"
                android:textColor="#ff28c0ff"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:textSize="14dp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

Could anyone can help me please? Thank you very much.

Comment: Try checking https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21627150/android-auto-resize-view-for-small-screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LinearLayout with match_parent height and width to wrap your ViewPager and other Views you want to be in the same row or column as your ViewPager. Remove explicit dimensions, then, add layout_weight property to Views wrapped by the LinearLayout. [More information on layout_weight in LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html).

If you want to support a large range of screens sizes and resolutions, I suggest you to read [this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), and look deeper in the [android developers website](https://developer.android.com/index.html) for best practices and instructions to make your app behave weel on (almost) all screen sizes.

Comment: should I use wrap_content for my ViewPager?

Comment: I removed my explicit dimensions and just used wrap_content on my ViewPager and also add layout_weight in my ViewPager. I put my ViewPager inside a LinearLayout and it now extends to what i wanted but when testing it to smaller devices my problem still occurs.

Comment: No, you shouldn't use wrap_content for a Viewpager as you don't want your ViewPager's size to change when you are on a smaller view page. And I guess you can't predict the size of the ViewPager content. You should set it to match_parent. But as I said, if your ViewPager is in a LinearLayout with a layout_weight, if your LinearLayout orientation is vertical, you shouldn't specify any height for your LinearLayout child's. If your LinearLayout orientation is horizontal, same, but for the width. Don't forget to add a layout_weight to all child's in this case. And don't look at the ugly @이남웅's code

Comment: Let me know if my solution works. I you need it, I will edit my response to help you :)

Comment: Hi i used match_parent in both of my LinearLayout and ViewPager for layout_height, also inserted layout_weight="1" in my ViewPager which is the LinearLayout child but i still get the same problem :(

Comment: should i put match_parent also in my ScrollView? which is in my viewpager_item.xml

Comment: it works now i also put layout_weight in CirclePageIndicator. But i wonder if this is the only fixed height of it? i haven't tried it yet to large devices like nexus 5. I want the LinearLayout to adjust whenever the screen is big or small.

Comment: i tried using 0px instead of match_parent and still uses layout_weight i tried using layout_weight="3" and for the viewpager and layout_weight="1" for my CirclePageIndicator  this is really a big help you @Louis Cognault :D

Comment: You're welcome :)
PS:
You should use match_parent when you want your view height/width to match the parent's one.

Answer (score 0):

i make some class to resize view's width and height. I dont like Dp unit. it's hard to me, every device fit.

here part of my class :

```
public class SetViewScale {
    private static SetViewScale instance;
    public int height, width; //device height, width
    public final static int Full_w = 720; // base on design
    public final static int Full_h = 1230; //base on design

private SetViewScale(Activity a){
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    a.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    int deviceWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    int deviceHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
    this.width  = deviceWidth;
    this.height = deviceHeight;
}
private SetViewScale(WindowManager wm){
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    int deviceWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    int deviceHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
    this.width  = deviceWidth;
    this.height = deviceHeight;
}

public synchronized static SetViewScale getInstance(Activity a){
    if(instance == null)
        instance = new SetViewScale(a);
    return instance;
}
public synchronized static SetViewScale getInstance(WindowManager wm){
    if(instance == null)
        instance = new SetViewScale(wm);
    return instance;
}

public synchronized static SetViewScale getInstance(){
    if(instance == null) {
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) AppManager.context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        instance = new SetViewScale(wm);
    }
    return instance;
}
/**
 * view resizing device width height
 * @param view
 * @param w 
 * @param h
 * @return
 */
public View setViewScale(View view, int w, int h) {
    int setW, setH;

    int x = width * w;
    setW = (int)(x/Full_w);
    int y = h*setW;
    setH = (int)(y/w);
    ViewParent parent = view.getParent();
    if(parent instanceof LinearLayout){
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        lp.width = setW;
        lp.height = setH;
        view.setLayoutParams(lp);
    }else if(parent instanceof RelativeLayout){
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();
        lp.width = setW;
        lp.height = setH;
        view.setLayoutParams(lp);
    }else if(parent instanceof FrameLayout){
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();
        lp.width = setW;
        lp.height = setH;
        view.setLayoutParams(lp);
    }else if(parent instanceof AbsListView){
        AbsListView.LayoutParams lp = (AbsListView.LayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();
        lp.width = width;
        lp.height = height;
        view.setLayoutParams(lp);
    }else{
        return null;
    }
    return view;
}
public View setFillWidthScale(View view, int w, int h) {
    int setW, setH;

    int x = width * w;
    setW = (int)(x/Full_w);
    int y = h*setW;
    setH = (int)(y/w);
    ViewParent parent = view.getParent();
    if(parent instanceof LinearLayout){
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        lp.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        lp.height = setH;
        view.setLayoutParams(lp);
    }else if(parent instanceof RelativeLayout){
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();
        lp.width = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        lp.height = setH;
        view.setLayoutParams(lp);
    }else if(parent instanceof FrameLayout){
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();
        lp.width = FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        lp.height = setH;
        view.setLayoutParams(lp);
    }else if(parent instanceof AbsListView){
        AbsListView.LayoutParams lp = (AbsListView.LayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();
        lp.width = width;
        lp.height = height;
        view.setLayoutParams(lp);
    }else{
        return null;
    }
    return view;
}
```

use px unit.

i hope it is some hint to you.